# How can I load data from table on jsp page in specific range?

Tags: database, jsp, spring-mvc

[The Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kl9Hx.png)

I have a table on my jsp page. There are more than thousand of data in the table. I want to add a paging system on table in such way that when I click 1 number page , then selected number of data will be loaded only, such as 20 number row only will be loaded . Then when I select page no 2, the loaded row will be from 21th row to 40th row only.
As like as google page loading system.
    Here is my Code:

```
 function createDynamicTable(data){   

            currentbatchitemData = eval(data);  

            for(var i = 0; i < currentbatchitemData.length; i++){

                    var code  = currentbatchitemData[i].empCode; 
                    var name  = currentbatchitemData[i].empName;    
                    var salary = 0 ;
                    var income = currentbatchitemData[i].incomeYear;
                    var month = currentbatchitemData[i].month ;
                    var des = currentbatchitemData[i].batchDesc;

                    var tableInfo = "<tr>";
                    tableInfo +=
                                '<td class="table-td-text-color">' + code  + '</td>' +  
                                '<td class="table-td-text-color">' + name  + '</td>' +
                                '<td class="table-td-text-color">'+ salary + '</td>' +
                                '<td class="table-td-text-color">' + 
                                '<button type="button" class="btn-edit btn btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></button>'+
                                '<button type="button" onclick="delRow(this);" class="btn-del btn btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button>' +'</td>';         

                    $("#currentbatchitem tbody").append(tableInfo);             
                } 

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#currentbatchitem').DataTable();
            });

                $("#income_year").val(income);
                $("#pay_month").val(month);
                $("#batch_description").val(des);
            InitHandlers();
        /* }

     }) ;*/     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement server processing inorder to achieve your goal.

Please follow the link.

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html